# failure to persist data to the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have been trying to check whether the tables are present in mySQL database using workbench however i keep on getting this error.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.5.2)[0;39m

[2m2021-07-09 14:26:47.431[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.i.app.IssueTrackingApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting IssueTrackingApplication using Java 15.0.2 on User with PID 1224 (C:\Users\26097\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite projects\IssueTracking\target\classes started by 26097 in C:\Users\26097\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite projects\IssueTracking)
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:47.436[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.i.app.IssueTrackingApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:47.514[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:47.514[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:48.645[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:48.756[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 98 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:49.623[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:49.638[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:49.638[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:49.773[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:49.774[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2259 ms
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:50.056[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:50.152[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:50.459[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:50.632[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:51.150[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:51.173[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: com.issuetracking.app.SQLDialect
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:52.215[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
    
    create table equipments_list (
       no integer not null,
        description varchar,
        location varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        primary key (no)
    )
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:52.238[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table equipments_list (
       no integer not null,
        description varchar,
        location varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        primary key (no)
    )" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table equipments_list (
       no integer not null,
        description varchar,
        location varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        primary key (no)
    )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.issuetracking.app.IssueTrackingApplication.main(IssueTrackingApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',
        location varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
     ' at line 3
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

[2m2021-07-09 14:26:52.239[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
    
    create table issues_list (
       no integer not null,
        description varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        location varchar,
        primary key (no)
    )
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:52.242[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table issues_list (
       no integer not null,
        description varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        location varchar,
        primary key (no)
    )" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table issues_list (
       no integer not null,
        description varchar,
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        location varchar,
        primary key (no)
    )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.issuetracking.app.IssueTrackingApplication.main(IssueTrackingApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',
        name_of_equipment varchar not null,
        location varchar,
     ' at line 3
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

[2m2021-07-09 14:26:52.243[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
    
    create table supervisor_comments (
       id bigint not null,
        comment varchar,
        primary key (id)
    )
[2m2021-07-09 14:26:52.246[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table supervisor_comments (
       id bigint not null,
        comment varchar,
        primary key (id)
    )" via JDBC Statement
```

how can I fix this cause I have placed all the properties in the application properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdatabase.db
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = Mofya2705$#

#Hibernate
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.mySQL5InnoDBDialect

#hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG; 

#spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.issuetracking.app.SQLDialect
```

And this is how i have named the database in workbench
[![name of schema][1]][1]

Above is my pom file.

however, itred multiple ways to modify the code but still to no avail. what could i be missing?

Comment: Are you creating table manually by DDL or creating through hibernate by automatically (spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update)?   If it created automatically then attach the model class also.

Comment: @SelvakumarAnushan yes it is through (spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update) i m new at spring boot . So how do i attach the model class which in my case is `package com.issuetracking.app.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table( name = "user")
public class User {...}`

Comment: found the issue.

Comment: if you going to create a table automatically you should have @Column(length = 255) on String feilds

Comment: if you not provide any length then will causing the problem

Comment: your auto-generation don't have VARCHAR(size) that the issue. do like below

Comment: @Column(name = "columnName", nullable = false, length = 255)

Comment: @SelvakumarAnushan tried that it did not work.

Comment: Try to remove the hibernate dependency and keep the spring-data-jpa dependency only

Comment: Can y ping your pom file

Comment: @SelvakumarAnushan this is what I get when I enter data. `2021-07-09 19:22:42.406[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m12312[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-6][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_3_,
        user0_.email as email2_3_,
        user0_.first_name as first_na3_3_,
        user0_.last_name as last_nam4_3_,
        user0_.password as password5_3_ 
    from
        user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.email=? `

Comment: This seems fine this mean your table got created right you have different issue now ?

Comment: @SelvakumarAnushan yes thats right. The issue i am having is that the data is not been stored in the database. but manually it is been committed to the database.

Comment: Is it possible to ping the error log

Comment: its not showing the error log that what i sent is what its telling me.

Comment: it doesnt throw any exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was validation your mysql query syntax that you have used to create the tables, seems they have syntax problems.

Syntax validated here
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Try these syntax

```
create table equipments_list (
 no integer not null,
 description VARCHAR(20),
location VARCHAR(20),
name_of_equipment VARCHAR(20) not null,
primary key (no)
)

create table issues_list (
  no integer not null,
  description varchar(20),
  name_of_equipment varchar(20) not null,
  location varchar(20),
  primary key (no)
)

create table supervisor_comments (
  id BIGINT not null,
  comment varchar(20),
  primary key (id)
)
```

Comment: have managed to get to works thanks. only problem i am having is saving the data in the database when i enter it in a form.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it worked for you